# installing Oracle JDK 8 on Debian 9

Tags: java, debian

I always installed Oracle JDK 8 on Debian 8 using the following instructions with no problems

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

But on Debian 9 when I execute the following command

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
```

I get the following errors

```
root@debian:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.OEi3EFigqe/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.OEi3EFigqe/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

How can I install Oracle JDK 8 on Debian 9?

Comment: It seems that dirmngr is not installed: **gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory**. You could try to install it via `apt-get install dirmngr` and retry

Comment: @DrHopfen that solved it

Comment: @DrHopfen Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that dirmngr is not installed: gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory. You could try to install it via apt-get install dirmngr and retry.

Answer (score 3):

You can install it manually if you want,
download the JDK8

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie:oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

make it in the environment variables of your OS:

```
JAVA_HOME= ~/path_Of_Your_JDK_DIR
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

I hope that help you Arya.

Comment: You can follow the steps in this  [link](http://fr.wikihow.com/installer-Oracle-Java-JDK-sur-Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: @sudoz thank's a lot, can you vote for my response please

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix with the following commands:

1. apt remove gnupg
2. apt install --reinstall gnupg2 (possibly not necessary, but doesn't hurt)
3. apt install dirmngr